# Как переименовать свойство интерфейса или абстрактное свойство в производном классе?

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Это мои хотелки:

```
public class Base<T> => abstract T Children {get;set;};
public class Derived<myclass> => myclass AnotherNameProp {get;set};
```

Вместо абстрактного класса может быть интерфейс.

В VB проблема решается примерно так:

Private Sub **AnotherSomething()** Implements **IDemo.DoSomething**

Как это сделать в C#?

Comment: Встречный вопрос: Зачем?

Comment: @Виктор В разных производных классах свойство имеет разный смысл.

Comment: Значит что-то с классами не то. Если классы наследуются от одного, то и свойство во всех классах должно иметь одинаковый смысл, иначе зачем новый класс наследовать от класса, к котором свойства имеют разный смысл

Comment: почитайте SOLID принципы, а в точности L. Вам должно стать понятно почему так не делают

Comment: Почему не делают, я знаю. Но так не делает C#, а VB отлично делает. И мне надо. Я могу, конечно, этот модуль на VB написать. Но не хотелось бы множить сущности. Я имею ввиду - языки.

Comment: Вы @AzizUmarov, кстати, неправы. Вот этот конструкт Implements IDemo.DoSomething отлично реализует L из SOLID в VB. Хотелось бы такой же в C#.

Comment: Да пожалуйста,  @Виктор. Например, в интерфейсе может свойство Количество, а в производных классах свойства Вес или Штуки. С последующей разной логикой обработки.

Comment: @Владимир Тогда надо делать разные классы (Вам же написали - про принцип SOLID почитайте )

Comment: @Виктор Это и есть разные классы, производные. Или Вы во имя SOLID и наследование отмените? Кстати, по поводу SOLID я уже ответил. На самом деле все проще. C# - строго типизированный язык, строже, чем VB. Ну концепция такая. В данном конкретном случае мне это мешает. А SOLID здесь ни при чем.

Comment: @Владимир Или Вы во имя SOLID и наследование отмените? - не понятно почему SOLID запрещает наследование в целом. Это принцип который рекомендуют использовать - принцип не есть закон. Если вы хотите чесать ухо через рот эт ваше дело, никто Вам этого не запрещает.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Вы читать умеете? Это был риторический вопрос. Как раз SOLID никакого наследования не отменяет, в отличие от Виктора, который (почему-то во имя SOLID) полагает, что производные классы - это все один класс. Спасибо за Ваши комментарии, больше не надо.